# Visual Studio abrindo multiplas janelas do navegador

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Como faz com que ambos projetos abram em somente uma guia do Google Chrome ?

Processo sendo realizado,

Click na Solução -> Propriedades -> Propriedades de Configuração -> Define ambos projetos para serem compilados

Resultado atual:

Ambos abrem em janelas distintas do google chrome.

Resultado esperado:

Ambos abrirem em uma mesma janela do google chrome em abas distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário alterar duas configurações para isso, sendo elas:

**Tolls>Options>Debugging** || **Ferramentas>Opções>Depuração**

1) Desmarcar a opção "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome, Edge and IE)"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2) Ainda com a janela de opções abertas, abra a aba *Projects and Solutions*(Projetos e soluções), clique na opção *Web Projects* e desmarque a opção "Stop debugger...."
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A solução proposta não resolveu o problema, ainda sim quando mando executar ele abre o projeto em duas abas.

Answer (score -1):

Talvez não seja a resposta desejada, esse resultado esperado só vi com Microsoft Edge.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Puts, então quer dizer que não consigo utilizar na mesma aba com o Chrome?